# R - Sorting DF across Rows by Date (transform, sort) & converting back to DF without losing changes

Tags: r, sorting, row, transform

I am having trouble re-arranging my data frame to organize dates that team members joined a team from first to last. However, my data need to be arranged across rows rather than columns.

For example, I have 6 columns, each containing the date that the team member joined a team. A single team is spread across the 6 columns by row. The original data, however, may show that the Team Member 3 joined before Team member 1.

Teams are different sizes, minimum 1 person, maximum 6 people. In the below example, the first team is two people (e1, e2) on row 1, the second team is three (e1,e2,e3) on row 2, etc.

My original Data example:

```
e1 <- c("2015-09-21", "2014-01-25", "2014-11-06")
   e2 <- c("2015-10-13", "2014-01-25", "2014-11-06")
   e3 <- c(NA, "2014-01-25", "2014-09-24")
   e4 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
   e5 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
   e6 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
   reg_dates_df <- data.frame (e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6)
```

To try to fix this problem, I have tried the following code:

```
reg_dates_list <- t(apply(reg_dates_df, 1, sort))
reg_dates_list <- t(reg_dates_list)

reg_dates_ordered <- rbindlist(lapply(reg_dates_list, as.data.frame.list),    fill = TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, it returns the data frame the same way, rather than maintaining the fixed order that came from using the sort command. I am not sure how to fix the new sorted vectors in the matrix so they will not change back to their original positions when converting back to a DF.

I would like the data frame to look like this (see changes across row three), with the dates of the person who joined first to be in e1, etc.

```
e1 <- c("2015-09-21", "2014-01-25", "2014-09-24")
e2 <- c("2015-10-13", "2014-01-25", "2014-11-06")
e3 <- c(NA, "2014-01-25", "2014-11-06")
e4 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
e5 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
e6 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
reg_dates_df_ordered2 <- data.frame (e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easier if it is a character matrix as follows:

```
t(apply(as.matrix(reg_dates_df), 1, sort, na.last=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Data frames are designed to operate on columns.  The `reg_dates_ordered` data frame that you constructed is a mixture of factors and logical values, which is likely to give you surprises later.

```
> summary(reg_dates_df)
          e1             e2             e3       e4             e5         
 2014-01-25:1   2014-01-25:1   2014-01-25:1   Mode:logical   Mode:logical  
 2014-11-06:1   2014-11-06:1   2014-09-24:1   NA's:3         NA's:3        
 2015-09-21:1   2015-10-13:1   NA's      :1                                
    e6         
 Mode:logical  
 NA's:3
```

As suggested by chinsoon12, if you really want to organise your data by rows, `matrix` of `character` values will probably better fit your needs.  If you want to stick with data frames, also note the `stringsAsFactors` options to ensure that your dates stay in character format.

Is it really necessary to organise your data by rows for the work done *in* R?  If you need to export the final result by rows, then you can work by columns, and transpose at the last moment.  Then, within R, your data frames would look like that:

```
t1 <- c("2015-09-21", "2015-10-13", NA, NA, NA, NA)
t2 <- c("2014-01-25", "2014-01-25", "2014-01-25", NA, NA, NA)
t3 <- c("2014-11-06", "2014-11-06", "2014-09-24", NA, NA, NA)
reg_dates_df4 <- data.frame(t1, t2, t3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> reg_dates_df4
          t1         t2         t3
1 2015-09-21 2014-01-25 2014-11-06
2 2015-10-13 2014-01-25 2014-11-06
3       <NA> 2014-01-25 2014-09-24
4       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
5       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
6       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

And you can loop on them with `lapply`.

```
> as.data.frame(lapply(reg_dates_df4, sort, na.last=T), stringsAsFactors=F)
          t1         t2         t3
1 2015-09-21 2014-01-25 2014-09-24
2 2015-10-13 2014-01-25 2014-11-06
3       <NA> 2014-01-25 2014-11-06
4       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
5       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
6       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

If you get tired of `stringsAsFactors`, have a look at `?as.POSIXct` for instance, to store the dates as dates instead of just characters.